# useState won't update state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to update a state using `useState` hook, however the state won't update.

```
const handleSelect = address => {
    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(address => {
        const receivedAddress = address[0];
        const newAddress = {
          street: receivedAddress.address_components[1].long_name,
          number: receivedAddress.address_components[0].long_name,
          city: receivedAddress.address_components[3].long_name,
          country: receivedAddress.address_components[5].long_name,
          zip: receivedAddress.address_components[6].long_name,
          selected: true
        };
        handleAddressSelection(newAddress);
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  };
```

When `handleSelect` is called, it creates the object `newAddress`, and then calls `handleAddressSelection` passing `newAddress`.

```
function handleAddressSelection(newObj) {
    console.log(newObj);
    Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function(key) {
      setValues({ ...values, [key]: newObj[key] });
    });
  }
```

In `console.log(newObj)` the object is filled fine, with all the data I need. Then I call `setValues` for each object in `newObj`, however no matter what, the `values` object won't receive the new data. The only one that is updated is `selected: true`, all others won't update.

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: I'd suggest creating an [mcve]. There's not a lot to go on here. For example, you never call `useState`, but you do make use of some undeclared variables. Trying to guess at that stuff is not going to generate super meaningful answers.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html, you should get lint errors, how are you using a hook inside a loop?

Comment: I'm assuming `setValues` is your setter, but how are you using it in a completely independent function?

Comment: @Adam `setValues` is inside a custom hook

Comment: @OtavioBonder - how is `setValues` getting into this custom hook? Is it in the same scope? Can you please show your component in more of it's entirety, we don't need to see the actual stuff that's being rendered, but show us how you're trying to use your hooks.

Comment: @Adam, yes, `const [values, setValues] = useState(initialState);` is in the same scope as `handleAddressSelection`. The problem was that I needed to call `setValues` with the callback variant of `useState`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling setValues multiple times in a loop, and every time you do so, you spread the *original* values, and thus overwrite anything that was done on the previous setValues. Only the very last setValues ends up working, which happens to be the one for `selected: true`

If you need to base your update on the previous value of the state, you should use the function version of setValues, as in:

```
Object.keys(newObj).forEach(function(key) {
  setValues(oldValues => ({ ...oldValues, [key]: newObj[key] }));
});
```

But even better would be to only call setValues once. If you're calling it multiple times, then you're going to generate multiple renders. I'd do this:

```
setValues(oldValues => ({...oldValues, ...newObj}));
```

Answer (score 1):

Values is not even defined anywhere in your examples. My guess is, it's some cached copy and you should be using callback variant of the state setter instead:

```
setValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, [key]: newObj[key] }));
```